# MAUI Draw line on canvas during runtime after button click

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I want to draw a new line in a GraphicsView after the click of a button.
This will draw the line on startup but I would like to either redraw the current line or preferably add another line to the view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CoachesToolbox.Controls"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:CoachesToolbox.ViewModel"
             xmlns:mct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:drawable="clr-namespace:CoachesToolbox.Models"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainViewModel"
             x:Class="CoachesToolbox.Views.MainPage"
             Title="CoachesToolBox demos"
             >
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <drawable:Drawable x:Key="MyDrawable" />

    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

```
<GraphicsView x:Name="Canvas"
                          HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                          VerticalOptions="Fill"
                          Drawable="{StaticResource MyDrawable}"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          Grid.Row="0"
                          BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
```

```
namespace CoachesToolbox.Models
{
    public class Drawable : IDrawable
    {
        public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
        {
            canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
            canvas.StrokeSize = 5;
            canvas.DrawLine(10, 10, 90, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can refer to this doc: [GraphicsView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/graphicsview?view=net-maui-7.0) by official.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, drawing on a canvas doesn't work that way. You can't "add" something on a canvas. It just draws what you tell it to draw.

You could increment an `int` with each button click and have a `for loop` to draw each line.

Answer (score -1):

remove attribute Drawable on Canvas. // to test.

add x:name="NAMED_RESOURCE" to resource declaration in ContentPage.Resource

add button with clicked event.

```
<Button 
    Text="Add Drawing"
    Clicked="Button_Clicked" 
    VerticalOptions="Start"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"></Button>

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Canvas.Drawable = NAME_RESOURCE;
}
```